# How to force cURL to send a complete URL as request target?

Tags: php, url, curl

How does I force curl to include the complete URL in the HTTP GET request?

Curl sends (not working):

```
GET /some/path HTTP/1.1
Host: my-domain-here.com
...
```

I want it to be (working):

```
GET http://my-domain-here.com/some/path HTTP/1.1
Host: i2.wp.com
```

So I want the host to be always included in the GET line. How can I do this using CURL/PHP?
The server can only handle absolute URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP cURL wrapper does not expose a way of doing this as far as I know.

Also, cURL will automatically change the `Host` header even if you specify a different one.
For example:

```
curl -v --dump-header - -0 -H 'Host: my-domain.com' http://subdomain.my-domain.com/something.html
```

will ignore the custom header and send this:

```
GET /something.html HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
Host: subdomain.my-domain.com
Accept: */*
```

What you can do is [build the request manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164405/show-curl-post-request-headers-is-there-a-way-to-do-this#answer-3164510):

```
$host = 'my-domain.com';
$path = 'http://subdomain.my-domain.com/something.html';

$fp = fsockopen($host, 80);

fputs($fp, "GET $path HTTP/1.1\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Content-length: 0\r\n");
fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

$result = ''; 
while(!feof($fp)) {
    $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
}

fclose($fp);

echo $result;
```

Comment: curl/7.29.0 does allow to override the Host header.

Answer (score 2):

At least from the command line, curl does send absolute URIs if you configure it to use a HTTP proxy for the request. Even if you're not using a proxy, you can specify that that it use the actual server as the proxy server, and your server will then receive the absolute URI in the request.

Comment: cURL using PHP also does this, I'm looking for a way to prevent it and froce cURL to send the relative URL.

Comment: Do you mean like using the flag: `--proxy1.0 example.com:80`?

Answer (score 2):

## `curl` has `--request-target` option

The following command will

- Connect to `127.0.0.1`
- Send request path as `GET http://request.host.name/path/ HTTP/1.1`
- Set `Host` header to `Host: host.header`

```bash
curl http://127.0.0.1 -v \
  --request-target http://request.host.name/path/ \
  --path-as-is \
  -H "Host: host.header"
```

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET http://request.host.name/path/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: host.header
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.14.0
< Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2022 10:14:14 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 169
< Connection: keep-alive
<
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

Answer (score 1):

`curl` always acts as a correct HTTP client. The [standard requires](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.1) that the request target (i.e. what follows the GET) only consists of an absolute path and optionally a query.

So it is not possible to make `curl` send an absolute URL as request target to an origin server.