# CURL Errors POSTing File

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to hit the Census Geocoding API via Curl in PHP. Here's (a trimmed down version of) my code:

```
$post = array('benchmark' => 'Public_AR_CENSUS2010', 'addressFile'=>'@C:\TestData.csv');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);

echo($result);
curl_close ($ch);
```

This results in getting an error back from the API:

```
"From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1: 10.4.1 400 Bad Request. The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."
```

However, if I invoke Curl form the command line, it works fine...

```
curl --form addressFile=@"C:\TestData.csv" --form benchmark=PUBLIC_AR_CENSUS2010 http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/addressbatch
```

Any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: If one works and the other does, compare the headers sent to determine what is missing. You can add `-v` on the command line and [read the highest voted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164405/show-curl-post-request-headers-is-there-a-way-to-do-this) for PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be on PHP version 5.6, in which case the `@` feature is deprecated and turned off by default. It can still be enabled by explicit `curl_setopt` setting:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I already switched to using `curl_file_create`, which I guess is now the PHP 5.6-approved way of doing things... but this explains why I needed to!