Translating CLI curl command into PHP
I have the following curl command (with data changed to protect the innocent:
curl -s -i -k -X POST https://myserver.mydomain.com/rest/login -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"username": "myuser","password":"mypass","domain":"mydomain"}'

This works perfectly from the command line and I get an appropriate response.
I have attempted to turn this into a PHP curl request with the following code:
$ch = curl_init();
$postFields = json_encode([
    "username"=>$myuser,
    "password"=>$mypass,
    "domain"=>$mydomain
]);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://" . $myserver . "/rest/login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type:application/json']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$webresponse = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($webresponse);
print_r($info);

However, when I run this, I get nothing from the webresponse and the $info shows:
Array
(
    [url] => https://myserver.domain.com/rest/login
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 0
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.007508
    [namelookup_time] => 0.008522
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => -1
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 0
    [local_ip] => 
    [local_port] => 0
    [http_version] => 0
    [protocol] => 0
    [ssl_verifyresult] => 0
    [scheme] => 
    [appconnect_time_us] => 0
    [connect_time_us] => 0
    [namelookup_time_us] => 8522
    [pretransfer_time_us] => 0
    [redirect_time_us] => 0
    [starttransfer_time_us] => 0
    [total_time_us] => 7508
)

Any help anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Your example code is a bit confusing. Does $myserver actually contain "myserver.mydomain.com" or just "myserver" as the name suggests? Apart from that, the code looks good to me. Sometimes a service requires a valid CURLOPT_USERAGENT, but I doubt that's the case here. You do realize there's no way for us to test anything?

$myserver is just a variable to hold the server name.  This is a Horizon connection server that I'm attempting to authenticate to.  The irony here is that I can connect easily with the curl command or with a similar curl command from PowerShell, so I'm completely stumped.

Try adding this to the end to print any errors if (curl_errno($ch)) {     echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch); }

I have it dumping the curl_error response and it's empty as well.

Try and put a space between header name and value, some systems are sensitive in that regard. 'Content-Type: application/json'

To debug further, you could investigate exactly what headers cURL is sending - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164405/show-curl-post-request-headers-is-there-a-way-to-do-this

As it turns out, this was an selinux issue, rather than a PHP issue.  The web server was not allowed to make external HTTP requests.  Once I enabled that with "setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on", I was able to get requests to go through.
Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

I assumed you executed the CLI command, and ran the PHP script, on the same server. Clearly the curl command didn't work "perfectly" on the web server? It's those little things that can take forever to diagnose. SELinux has sometimes been the bane of life as well. Nice to hear that you solved it.

The curl command ran perfectly on the server.  The entire issue was that the web server was simply not allowed to make external HTTP calls.   That's why it was so vexing when I could get it to work in multiple other ways on the same server but not in the web server.  I likely could have also figured it out if I was able to run the PHP script from the command line but, unfortunately, the script in question is an AJAX interaction script so it only works when sent parameters from an HTTP request.
