# How to get info on sent PHP curl request

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I'm trying to debug a curl request to a webservice 'getToken' endpoint.

I'm not 100% confident that the URL and the auth info is getting written in to the curl handle correctly.

I'm trying to use `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);` to capture the sent request, but it doesn't give me much info. Is there a way to get more in depth diagnostics about what the actual curl request looks like?

Here's the code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // just getting header to see if we got an auth token
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1); // capture the header info
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // turn verbose on    
// execute the curl request 

$rh = fopen("request.txt", "w"); // open request file handle
$verbose = fopen('php://temp', 'rw+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);

curl_exec($ch); // execute request

$sent_request = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
fwrite($rh, $sent_request); // save the request info
fclose($rh);
!rewind($verbose);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbose);

echo "Verbose information:\n<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";
```

This all works as far as it goes, but returns a 401 every time-- the API admin assures me that the username / pass I have is correct.

I was wondering if I'm somehow getting the URL value wrong, or not sending the right username / pass, but this info isn't printed in the request data saved:

```
HEAD /export/auth HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Y2FpcmRzdW5mYTpENWlAaVM4cw==
Host: webservices.mycompany.com
Accept: */*
```

You can see that the username/pass is not recorded (I assume for security). The endpoint URL  I think is the `host` value plus the start of the `HEAD` value, so `webservices.mycompany.com/export/auth`?

The "Verbose Information" statement prints nothing. Not sure why on this either!

Thanks for help.

EDIT: added verbose mode from [Php - Debugging Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl) thanks to commenter immulatin

Comment: You can set verbose to true: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl

Comment: First thing I would check is I'd make a much more simple request with minimum parameters and typed all my variables values manually (url, login, password). Wired errors like that are usually caused by malformed input such as extra spaces etc.

Comment: I think this old post could be useful

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866946/how-can-i-see-the-request-headers-made-by-curl-when-sending-a-request-to-the-ser>

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you set `CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT` to `true`, outgoing headers are available in the array returned by `curl_getinfo()`, under `request_header` key:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://foo.com/bar");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "someusername:secretpassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

curl_exec($ch);

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info['request_header']);
```

This will print:

```
GET /bar HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic c29tZXVzZXJuYW1lOnNlY3JldHBhc3N3b3Jk
Host: foo.com
Accept: */*
```

Note the auth details are base64-encoded:

```
echo base64_decode('c29tZXVzZXJuYW1lOnNlY3JldHBhc3N3b3Jk');
// prints: someusername:secretpassword
```

Also note that username and password need to be percent-encoded to escape any URL reserved characters (`/`, `?`, `&`, `:` and so on) they might contain:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, urlencode($username).':'.urlencode($password));
```

Comment: After 7 years, still a very helpful comment and exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The `curl_getinfo()` must use after `curl_exec()`

Answer (score 6):

`curl_getinfo()` must be added before closing the curl handler

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/bar");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "someusername:secretpassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info['request_header']);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: The `curl_getinfo()` must use after `curl_exec()`, So your code was wrong!

Comment: And the lines have been switched, the answer corrected and the helpfulness increased :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a proxy tool like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to capture the outgoing request headers, data, etc. by passing the proxy details through `CURLOPT_PROXY` to your `curl_setopt_array` method.

For example:

```
$proxy = '127.0.0.1:8888';
$opt = array (
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.example.com",
    CURLOPT_PROXY => $proxy,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    );

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opt);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

The request is printed in a **request.txt** with details

```
$ch = curl_init();
$f = fopen('request.txt', 'w');
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL            => $url, 
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
CURLOPT_STDERR         => $f,
));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
fclose($f);
curl_close($ch);
```

You can also use curl_getinfo() function.