# Curl SOAP POST Request PHP 5.5.9

Tags: php, curl, soap

I would like someone with experience in SOAP requests with Curl and PHP to assist me. I have the situation where I am making SOAP PHP requests from my PHP app to remote server which is working great from my local server (PHP 7.0 , Curl 7.47 )
The problem is when I deploy the app on my server with PHP 5.5.9 and curl 7.50 , with completely same code, I get empty response from the Curl call. Here is the part of the code:

```
$xml_post_string  = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tcit="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/page/tcitems">';
        $xml_post_string .=     '<soapenv:Header/>';
        $xml_post_string .=     '<soapenv:Body>';
        $xml_post_string .=         '<tcit:ReadMultiple>';
        $xml_post_string .=         '</tcit:ReadMultiple>';
        $xml_post_string .=     '</soapenv:Body>';
        $xml_post_string .= '</soapenv:Envelope>'; 

   $headers = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: `here goes my remote url which I am calling`"
    );


    // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword); // username and password - declared at the top of the doc
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // the SOAP request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Actually I get empty string as a response, but when I debugged I saw that problem is 401 request (Something with auth?). Anyway the script is working perfectly from my localhost, so I suppose it is related to some version incopatibility on remote Server. Let me hear your thoughts and what do you think in this configuration can be the problem.

```
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); (this return 401)
$curl_errno= curl_errno($ch); (this returns 0)
```

Comment: First think is to analyse what `curl_error` has to say...

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread your question on the first read. Well, if it returns 401 then it is just a 401, unauthorised. Does the server has any whitelist functionality? Considering your credentials are correct. Can you access any log on the server side to see more details on why it was refused?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Credentials are correct because same code is working from my localhost. Whitelist seems interesting, you mean remote server which I am fetching has blocked the ip of my server for some reason? I don't have access to the fetching url server

Comment: Please try analysing the request sent, like described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24148421/557306) for example. Compare if there is any difference between your local and server requests. Shouldn't be, but who knows, there may be a software difference we are skipping here. If there is no difference, then it might be network related. I'd then try to reduce the request to a bare minimal that still reproduces the error to continue analysing.