# This cURL code does not work?

Tags: php, curl

I've asked my host plenty of times now if this was on their side, and they said no. Everything in cURL is working/enabled; **however**, whenever I try the below code, I can never get a connection or page returned (I've tested many differnet working proxies).

```
<?php

//THIS IS A TEST
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '114.80.136.112:7780');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
curl_exec($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Can anyone else test this function for me and see if they get any working results?

**EDIT: HAVE ALSO TRIED**

```
<?php

//THIS IS A TEST
$ch = curl_init('http://www.google.com');

$f = fopen('requests.txt', 'w');

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_PROXY => '114.80.136.112:7780',
    CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE => CURLPROXY_HTTP,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1',
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 40,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE        => 1,
    CURLOPT_STDERR         => $f,
));

curl_exec($ch);
fclose($f);
echo curl_error($ch);
print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

That returned this in *results.txt*

```
* About to connect() to proxy 114.80.136.112 port 7780 (#0)
*   Trying 114.80.136.112...
* Timeout
* connect() timed out!
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Maybe you have to be specific about the CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE parameter.

Comment: That didn't seem to help either. Updated main post with the code I tried. :/

Answer (score 0):

Return

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=p&amp;hl=zh-CN&amp;pref=hkredirect&amp;pval=yes&amp;q=http://www.google.com.hk/&amp;ust=1373746017821152&amp;usg=AFQjCNG2MqAeEfu9C9h5dmJu1n0YZWm5vw">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
Array
(
    [url] => http://www.google.com
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 302
    [header_size] => 580
    [request_size] => 191
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.733
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.328
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.328
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 376
    [speed_download] => 512
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 376
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.733
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => http://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=p&hl=zh-CN&pref=hkredirect&pval=yes&q=http://www.google.com.hk/&ust=1373746017821152&usg=AFQjCNG2MqAeEfu9C9h5dmJu1n0YZWm5vw
)
```

try check curl in `phpinfo();`

Comment: If it helps, here's some pictures of my phpinfo() output related to cURL. http://puu.sh/3C6EZ && http://puu.sh/3C6Ew

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set your PROXY TYPE as well:

```
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:9050' );
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5 );
```

Also, for debugging, [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) is invaluable. With it, you can craft HTTP requests (even to a service using HTTPS) to troubleshoot a remote service.

You should be able to generate the full request message that is sent by curl to your proxy by using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406238/278976).

Lastly, though this may not help you in this case, I wrote a standalone curl wrapper class in PHP. Adding methods to it or using as is my make it a bit easier to work with curl.

https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Http/OutgoingHttpRequest.md

https://github.com/homer6/altumo/blob/master/source/php/Http/OutgoingHttpRequest.php

Comment: Yeah, I just tried setting the PROXYTYPE to HTTP, yet it's still not returning anything. I've updated the OP to show the code I tried and results with your suggested method.