# PayPal IPN not working on Live

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

so I've been building this project and the IPN worked perfectly for my Sandbox - but as soon as I changed the URL to live, I got this log message.

I tried using this as a solution but still receiving the error.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name'));
```

**The Message response I get is**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <H1>Access Denied</H1>

    You don't have permission to access "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" on this server.<P>
    Reference #18.........    
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**The IPN im using is this one :**

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

**Can anyone please help. Thanks**

Comment: Sounds like a malformed HTTP Header - Akamai will block requests with missing user agent in certain countries. 

Can you check what is being sent out in the HTTP request? 

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866946/how-can-i-see-the-request-headers-made-by-curl-when-sending-a-request-to-the-ser for a how-to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I made an mistake, instead of adding in the additional line :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close', 'User-Agent: company-name'));
```

I had to acutally just add in :

```
, 'User-Agent: company-name'
```

in the line that already existed. It's working now.