# curl statement `--form input=@./thefile.pdf` in python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a curl statement as follows taken from this [link](http://grobid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Grobid-service/):

`curl -v -include --form input=@./thefile.pdf localhost:8080/processFulltextDocument`

I am trying to use Requests to replicate the above statement in Python and so am using the following code

```
    import requests
    Data = {'input': './samp.pdf'}
    url='http://127.0.0.1:8080/processFulltextDocument'
    r = requests.post(url,data=Data)
    print r.text
```

However, I receive a 415 error. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** The headers of the curl statement are as follows:

`curl -v -include --form input=@./samp.pdf 127.0.0.1:8080/processFulltextDocument`

```
* Couldn't find host 127.0.0.1 in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /processFulltextDocument HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 549488
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------df1c59f42e57cbf4
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

Comment: Using `@` for file names is specific to `curl`, see e.g. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144479/what-does-the-at-symbol-before-a-filename-mean-in-a-curl-command

Comment: @jonrsharpe I removed the `@` but I still get an error

Comment: then you're just posting the file name. If you don't understand the code you've copied, translating it will be near-impossible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I also tried `{'input': open('./samp.pdf', 'rb')}` but still get an error

Comment: For reference, assuming the HTTP error codes are being properly used, 415 is an "unsupported media type" HTTP error.

Comment: related: [How to send a “multipart/form-data” with requests in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12385179/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To send a "multipart/form-data" POST http request, use `files` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests  # $ pip install requests

r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/processFulltextDocument',
                  files=dict(input=open('samp.pdf', 'rb')))
print(r.text) # print response
```

See [POST a Multipart-Encoded File](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

Answer (score 1):

While the `@` is unique to curl, you can do this in requests (which should work):

```
import requests
Data = {'input': open('./samp.pdf', 'rb')}

url='http://127.0.0.1:8080/processFulltextDocument'
r = requests.post(url,data=Data)
print r.text
```

**Update 2:**

The code snippet is wrong. Change `r = requests.post(url,data=Data)` to `r = requests.post(url,files=Data)` and this will work. Copy paste error.

See also: [Example on Requests website](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)

**Update 1:** 
This will pass the file as a field in the post request. You can pass it as the body like so (I think):

```
import requests
Data = open('./samp.pdf', 'rb').read()

url='http://127.0.0.1:8080/processFulltextDocument'
r = requests.post(url,data=Data)
print r.text
```

Comment: added an update: maybe you need to pass the file as the post body (??)

Comment: I am afraid I already tried that before. Didn't work. The curl statement works perfectly though

Comment: @Ekoji have you tried verbose modes to see what it actually sends (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866946/how-can-i-see-the-request-headers-made-by-curl-when-sending-a-request-to-the-ser)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Or maybe should I try pycurl instead?