# Erlang hackney : send a mail in mailgun.com using attachement

Tags: erlang, mailgun

I'm trying to send an email via mailgun.com using the hackney and I have some issues sending attachments (which requires multipart).

https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#sending

Basically my interest fields are:

```
from
to
subject
text
attachment File attachment. You can post multiple attachment values. Important: You must use multipart/form-data encoding when sending attachments.
```

I tried the following:

```
PayloadBase =[
   {<<"from">>, From},
   {<<"to">>, To},
   {<<"subject">>, Subject},
   {<<"text">>, TextBody},
   {<<"html">>, HtmlBody}
],

Payload = case Attachment of
    null ->
       {form, PayloadBase};
    _->
       {multipart, PayloadBase ++ [{file, Attachment}]}
end,
```

But for some reason the attachment is not sent.. Everything else works as expected.
I don't see how I can set the filed name to "attachment" as required by mailgun .. at this this is what I suspect beeing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will fix the problem:

```
Payload2 = case Attachment of
    null ->
        {form, PayloadBase};
    _->
        FName = hackney_bstr:to_binary(filename:basename(Attachment)),
        MyName = <<"attachment">>,
        Disposition = {<<"form-data">>, [{<<"name">>, <<"\"", MyName/binary, "\"">>}, {<<"filename">>, <<"\"", FName/binary, "\"">>}]},
        ExtraHeaders = [],
        {multipart, PayloadBase ++ [{file, Attachment, Disposition, ExtraHeaders}]}
end,
```

Silviu

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used mailgun but I believe that you would need to put `attachment` as the field name. See [examples at the bottom of the page](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#examples) you posted:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages \
    -F from='Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>' \
    -F to='foo@example.com' \
    -F cc='bar@example.com' \
    -F bcc='baz@example.com' \
    -F subject='Hello' \
    -F text='Testing some Mailgun awesomness!' \
    --form-string html='<html>HTML version of the body</html>' \
    -F attachment=@files/cartman.jpg \
    -F attachment=@files/cartman.png
```

It will be easier if you make it working with `curl` first, then you can [debug what headers curl sends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866946/how-can-i-see-the-request-headers-made-by-curl-when-sending-a-request-to-the-ser) to the server. And then you can mimic that in Erlang.

This post explains [what `multipart/form-data` is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) and points to the [W3 document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) that provides examples how the data should be encoded.

Comment: with curl is properly working. but with hackeny I'm not able to make it work. I tried also {multipart, PayloadBase ++ [{file, Attachment, [{<<"name">>, <<"attachment">>}]}]}. but no luck.

Comment: Yeah, I am sure that both, the API and curl work fine. I mentioned curl so that you can debug what headers should be send and fix your code, not to check if it works.