# php saved file downloads as not expected

Tags: php

I have MySQL table with LONGBLOB column to save file (although I know saving files directly in database is not a good practice.) Saving works fine! concluding (C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\dogsport) size of dogsport has increased to the new file saved.

I have written download script part. File **downloads** to the computer fine (not displaying image in the webpage).

Problem: Downloaded file shows only 4 bytes although it should be 4.83 MB. When I open the image, image is not shown also (see screenshot)

[image]

What is the reason?

**Updated code for @Andrew:**

```
            $query = "SELECT Id,Name,Type,SizeMB FROM Upload"; // Good practice. Do not process much data here. leave Content field
        $result = mysqli_query ( $con, $query) or die ("Couldn't execute SELECT query: ". mysqli_error($con));
        $nrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo '<table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Id</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Type</td>
                        <td>Size (MB)</td>
                    </tr>';
        $selfpg = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){
            extract($row);
            echo "<tr>
                        <td>$Id</td>
                        <td>$Name</td>
                        <td>$Type</td>
                        <td>$SizeMB</td>
                        <td> <a href='$selfpg?id=$Id'> Download </a> </td>
                  </tr>";       
        }
        echo '</table>';

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        if ( isset($_GET['id']) ){

            $result_id = "SELECT Content FROM Upload WHERE Id=". $_GET['id'];

            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_id);
            extract($row);
            $size_bytes = $SizeMB * 1024 * 1024;
            header("Content-Type: ". $Type);
            header("Content-Length: ". $size_bytes);
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= ". $Name);

            echo $Content;
        }
        else{
            echo "<br>No id received to download a file</br>";
        }
```

Still there is the problem

**UPDATE !!! - Please download my code with SQL**

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=88155436688298142745

Comment: What is the download timeout for your script?

Comment: how do I check it? Manually I can see just few seconds (less than 5 seconds) to complete the download.

Comment: It's in the php.ini file

Comment: in php.ini there is no something called download_timeout.

Comment: What's the Content-Type header that's getting sent? It should be image/jpeg

Comment: yes. you are correct. it is image/jpeg and taken from the database

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be caused by this

```php
header("Content-Length: ". $SizeMB);
```

`Content-Length` header must contain size in bytes, not megabytes.

Also, `SELECT * FROM Upload` - this is bad practice. Your query will return all fields from table, including `longblob` column. You don't need to process so much data. In script you are using only `Id`, `Name`, `Type` and `SizeMB`, so select only those fields. And instead

```php
mysqli_data_seek($result,0);
```

you can perform second query:

```sql
SELECT Content FROM Upload WHERE Id = $Id
```

Comment: I made changes. thanks great best practice. But still the same problem. :(

Comment: SizeMB field in the table, I am saving records after converting to MB from bytes using $fsize = ($_FILES['photoUpload']['size']/1024)/1024; then I this it is rounded and saved because my SizeMB field is SizeMB DECIMAL(9,2) NOT NULL ... Is there any impact of this?

Comment: Content-length is optional. Try dropping it, see if that helps?

Comment: @Rob Gudgeon still the same problem exist. :(

Comment: Can you provide some more info? Maybe download your file [with curl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3121175/6209665) and show here verbose response? With all request/response headers as described in answer by link.

Comment: Ohh completely new topic for me CURL. I have to study it first. Also I have no web hosting. I can attach the file to my post. Then you can easily do a check.

Comment: @Andrew I have uploaded my code with SQL script. please check it. Thanks.

Comment: Just use Firefox or chrome, open the developer console, inspect network traffic & post the response headers & the actual response contents. No need for curl