# Trouble converting curl commands to python requests

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to grab some data from a website using API, but I'm having trouble converting the example curl command to python requests.

example curl command

```
curl -X POST "some_url" \
-H "accept: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: <accesstoken>" \
-d @- <<BODY 
{} 
BODY
```

My python requests that didn't work

```py
headers = {
    'Authorization': "Bearer {0}".format(access_token)
}

response = requests.request('GET', "some_url", 
                            headers=headers, allow_redirects=False)
```

I get error code 400, can anyone help me figure out what was wrong?

Comment: Your cURL request mentions POST but you're making a GET with the python code, any reason for that?

Comment: @razdi I tried with POST too but didn't work, I'm not familiar with the curl format so I just tried things out. Can you show me the correct format in python given this curl command?

Comment: This might not be the solution but the tool might actually get you close: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: what type of data is `BODY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent requests code for your curl should be:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': '<accesstoken>',
}

data = "{} "
response = requests.post('http://some_url', headers=headers, data=data)
```

You can use https://curl.trillworks.com/ to convert your actual curl invocation (note that it won't handle [heredocs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells), as in your example).

If you see different behavior between curl and your python code, dump the HTTP requests and compare:

- [Python requests - print entire http request (raw)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658572/python-requests-print-entire-http-request-raw)
- [How can I see the request headers made by curl when sending a request to the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866946/how-can-i-see-the-request-headers-made-by-curl-when-sending-a-request-to-the-ser)