# firefox does not allow CORS request

Tags: flask

vuejs is running inside a docker container served by:

```
CMD [ "http-server", "dist" ]
```

when using axios inside Vue.js mounted() to do a GET request against a flask api it shows "blocked" in the network tab, accessing other REST-API's works fine.

testing with curl (localhost:6000 being the flask server):
- curl is running from my real host and conneting to the container

```
curl -H "Origin: http://localhost:5000"   
-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET"   -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested With"   
-X OPTIONS --verbose  http://localhost:6000/todo/api/v1.0/wheel/40  

*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 6000 (#0)
> OPTIONS /todo/api/v1.0/wheel/40 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:6000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://localhost:5000
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5000
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT
< Vary: Origin
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Werkzeug/1.0.0 Python/3.8.2
< Date: Sun, 15 Mar 2020 15:43:44 GMT
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

from what ive read so far, for example here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866946/how-can-i-see-the-request-headers-made-by-curl-when-sending-a-request-to-the-ser), for a unauthorized GET request the headers look ok.

This one gets the real data:

```
curl -H "Origin: http://l:5000"   -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET"   -H "Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With"  -v http://localhost:6000/todo/api/v1.0/wheel/40 
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 6000 (#0)
> GET /todo/api/v1.0/wheel/40 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:6000
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://l:5000
> Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
> Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 39
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://l:5000
< Vary: Origin
< Server: Werkzeug/1.0.0 Python/3.8.2
< Date: Sun, 15 Mar 2020 15:56:43 GMT
< 
{"result":{"model 1":0,"model 2":150}}
* Closing connection 0
```

Manipulating -H "Origin..." to this:

```
-H "Origin: http://l:5000"
```

also shows a normal reply. Isn't that a good test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out mozilla allows certain ports for certain protocols as shown here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mozilla_Port_Blocking

6000 is the "x11" port and on that list - As port for x11 and not to be used for xhr. So every port not on that list should do the trick.
reason:
Cert issued a Vulnerability Note VU#476267 for a "Cross-Protocol" scripting attack, known as the HTML Form Protocol Attack

Answer (score 0):

In your app's `__init__.py` file add these lines and you'll be good to go.

```sh
$ pip install flask-cors
```

```py
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

Read more about CORS here-- [MDN CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: that is usually the right answer, i should have added that "tcpdump -i lo port 6000" did not show any traffic confirming that firefox does not send the data at all

Comment: If the API is accessible from CURL, that means the problem lies outside of Flask, could you perhaps share how you're making the API call in Vue.js

Comment: did you read the answer that was posted one day before your comment?