# How to upload file to flask application with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have the following `curl` command

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/image/cad1b12e-c374-4d46-b43b-3ddbe7d683c4" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@tests/test.jpg;type=image/jpeg"
```

I am trying to construct a `pytest` function with the same behavior that the command above but I am not getting the exact result, the `pytest` function is the following

```
url = "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/image/cad1b12e-c374-4d46-b43b-3ddbe7d683c4"

payload={}

files=[('file',('test.png',open('./tests/test.png','rb'),'image/png'))]
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer:

Don't specify a `Content-Type` in the headers dictionary, when providing a `files` argument to the `requests.request` method.

### Longer answer

I tried to test that functionality to my own Flask upload script.

This worked when removing `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` form the `headers` dictionary, otherwise the response was 400 bad request (see `response.content`)

I noted that after making the request, and inspecting `response.request.headers` I could see that

- when specifying that header it was part of the request, *as-is*:

  ```
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  ```
- however when **not** specifying it `requests` automatically generates the header with a [`boundary`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type#Directives), and the request succeeded:

  ```
   'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=1beba22d28ce1e2cdcd76d253f8ef1fe'
  ```

---

Also:

- To find the headers sent from curl, either by using [the trace method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866951/2052575) or if you have access to the server, printing `request.headers` within the upload route, you can see that the curl command automatically appends a `boundary` to the header, even when the flag `-H  "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"` is provided:

  ```
    Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------c263b5b9297c78d3
  ```
- The same can be observed via the Network tab in your browser dev-tools, when uploading via an HTML form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set as an attribute.

---

I had always thought that manually adding `'Content-Type:':'multipart/form-data'` to the headers dict was required, but it appears when using the the `files` argument to `requests.request` method, this is automatically generated with the `boundary`.

In fact the [`requests` docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) make no mention of setting this header yourself.

Comment: Exactly!Correct! but Postman code generator for python suggested these headers with `'Content-Type:':'multipart/form-data'`